# Is the sentence "This is the book which there are not many people who have read it." grammatical?

Tags: grammar

If the sentence above is grammatical, what is the role of "the book" in the relative clause?

I'm an EFL learner. I can understand the sentence "This is the book which there are not many people have read." I also think it is appropriate to add "it" after "read", so as to construct the sentence "there are not many people who have read it." However, I am confused about the fact that "which" is followed by a complete sentence.

Another similar structure is "the terrible robber [whom any man who can catch him must be a hero]". I read it in a paper. It is said if "him" is deleted, the sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

It is not grammatical. We can say

> This is the book. Not many people have read it.

but if you want to make it into one sentence, *which* takes the place of *it*.

> This is the book which not many people have read.

The phrase about the robber is much too complicated, although we sometimes find sentences like it in old-fashioned books. In my opinion it doesn't sound natural in modern English either with or without *him*, unless you break it up.

> [He is a] terrible robber. Anyone who can catch him must be a hero.